# using jquery to find all td's in a table by column position

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to add a class to the last cell in each row of a table...this does not work...it only applies the rightStyle to the last element in the first (top) row...

```
//the last cell in every row all have border right
                var lastIndex = getLastVisibleIndex();
                var rows = $("table.scrollable tr");
                rows.each(function () {
                    $("td:eq(" + lastIndex + ")").addClass(rightStyle)
                });
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell you what's wrong without knowing what's in getLastVisibleIndex and your markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the nth-child...

```
   $("table.scrollable td:nth-child(" + lastIndex + ")").addClass(rightStyle);
```

Some good alternative solutions here though.

Answer (score 15):

Do it all in one line...

```
$('table tr td:last-child').addClass(rightStyle);

// Targeting a particular column as pointed out by FiveTools
// Note that :nth-child(n) is 1-indexed
$('table tr td:nth-child(3)').addClass('highlight');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cobblers/hWqBU/

Answer (score 1):

When you search for tds, you need to look only inside the current row. See the addition of *this*:

```
            rows.each(function () {
                $("td:eq(" + lastIndex + ")", this).addClass(rightStyle)
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that your table rows don't all have `lastIndex` cells. Try this for more reliability:

```
rows.each(function () {
    $(this).children("td").last().addClass(rightStyle)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table.scrollable tr").each(function () {
                    $(this).children("td").eq(lastIndex).addClass(rightStyle);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing that you are doing, but I set the last td's column width

```
// SET FIRST AND LAST TD SIZE
$("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).children("td:last").attr("width", 200);
});
```